# How to display a categorical dataframe in a pairplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, encode, pairplot

I am getting the following error: `No variables found for grid columns`? In the console it prints the `dataframe` ok, but when I want to display it in seaborn, it doesn't work.

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cars_url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data'
cars_columns = ['buying', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons', 'lug_boot', 'safety', 'class']
data = pd.read_csv(cars_url, names = cars_columns)
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
plot(data1)

@interact(hue = ['buying'])
def plot(hue):
    _ = sns.pairplot(data1, hue = hue)
```

Comment: `data1 = pd.DataFrame(data)` is not necessary. `data = pd.read_csv(cars_url, names = cars_columns)` is already a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pairtplot works only with numerical data. You should use [Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) before paiplot.

For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
data = encoder.fit_transform(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. It somehow helped me. I will convert everything to numerical data.

Comment: This does not work as written. It results in `ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1728, 7) instead.`

Comment: @PaulViorel if this is used on each column, the transformed values will be reused in each column. `df.buying.unique() → array([3, 0, 2, 1])` and `df.maint.unique() → array([3, 0, 2, 1])`.

Comment: Y, you're right. Fixed that.